# convert range time data to datetime in pandas to_datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe 'DTime' column containing date & time data:

```
    01JAN2004 00:00-01:00
    01JAN2004 01:00-02:00
```

I tried to parse using:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DTime'], format='%d%b%Y %H:%M-%H:%M')
```

But this gives:

```
error: redefinition of group name 'H' as group 6; was group 4
```

I have tried removing the "-H:M" but this gives an 'unconverted data error.

Is there a way to do this and set the time base to the 1st given hour?

Comment: Well you need to determine what the final df should look like, are you wanting 2 datetimes from this range? Beg and end or you want the opening time only?

Comment: Opening time only in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        '01JAN2004 00:00-01:00',
        '01JAN2004 01:00-02:00'
        ], columns=['dstr'])

date_regex = '(?P<date>\d\d\w{3}\d{4})'
beg_regex = '(?P<beg_hour>\d\d):(?P<beg_min>\d\d)'
end_regex = '(?P<end_hour>\d\d):(?P<end_min>\d\d)'
regex = '{} {}-{}'.format(date_regex, beg_regex, end_regex)
d1 = df.dstr.str.extract(regex, expand=True)
for c in ['beg_hour', 'beg_min', 'end_hour', 'end_min']:
    d1[c] = d1[c].astype(int)

pd.concat([
        pd.to_datetime(d1.date, format='%d%b%Y') + \
        pd.to_timedelta(d1.beg_hour, unit='H'),
        pd.to_datetime(d1.date, format='%d%b%Y') + \
        pd.to_timedelta(d1.beg_hour, unit='H')
    ], axis=1, keys=['Beg', 'End'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have not used / seen a solution like this before. I only need Beg times but this is V useful for future