# Error when converting the date string to a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I receive the following error when trying to convert a date string to a datetime object

**error: redefinition of group name 'd' as group 6; was group 1**

I have imported a csv file which date column is a string - '01.01.2021 00:00 - 01.01.2021 01:00'

I want to convert this to a date time object so I can then extract the date, starttime & endtime into their own columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['01.01.2021 00:00 - 01.01.2021 01:00']})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M - %d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be *2* `datetime` objects?

Comment: Check the answer in this post, might help you solve your issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266154/convert-range-time-data-to-datetime-in-pandas-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

`pd.to_datetime` parses a string into a single datetime object. Also, a datetime object can store only single date.

`01.01.2021 00:00 - 01.01.2021 01:00` and its format `'%d.%m.%Y %H:%M - %d.%m.%Y %H:%M'` has 2 dates. since date is date `d` is present in both 1st and 6th group, you got this error

**error: redefinition of group name 'd' as group 6; was group 1**

I would suggest you to retrieve the string and parse it into 2 separate datetime objects and store this in 2 separate columns

Edit:
An example of this is provided in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20069844/sam-alloy), thanks to [sam_alloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20069844/sam-alloy)